# AWS LoadBalancer Client Certificate in HTTP Header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

In `2021` can the `AWS Loadbalancers` (`ELB`) forward the client certificate in a HTTP Header?

Currently the `ELB` load balancer is configured as a classic application load balancer,
forwarding both HTTP and HTTPS to the endpoint. I could alter this and use TCP,
but then I would loose the certificate management functionality provided by the AWS
Certificate Manager, auto renewing certificates.

Here is an example of `ASP.NET Core` endpoint, extracting the certificate from an `HTTP` Header variable: `X-SSL-CERT`

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddCertificateForwarding(options =>
      {
        options.CertificateHeader = "X-SSL-CERT";
        options.HeaderConverter = (headerValue) =>
        {
           X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;

           if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue))
           {
              byte[] bytes = StringToByteArray(headerValue);
              clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
           }

           return clientCertificate;
       };
    });
  }
```

My goal is to use AWS Managed Certificate's (Web Trusted) for authenticating the server, and self signed client certificates for authenticating the clients.
*I am not sure if this is possible yet, to have two different CA's (one CA not being public) when doing Mutual TLS.*